# Windows Universal App and SoundCloud login

Tags: authentication, soundcloud, win-universal-app

I have to work a bit with SoundCloud Api and Windows Universal App. My only problem for now is the login. Can anyone help me, as I had problem finding any article, with the way of login in from Windows Universal App to Soundcloud?

I guess I should render the Soundcloud login page within the app in Webview but what should be the redirect url for it?

Comment: Ok now I have figured out that I have to use WebAuthenticationBroker but does anyone know how to get application callback uri that will work?

Answer (score 0):

> You authenticate Mobile and Desktop Applications the same way you do
>   for Server-side Web Applications. To make the flow smoother, you can
>   use a redirect_uri with a custom protocol scheme and set your app as a
>   handler for that protocol scheme. For example, your redirect_uri could
>   be something like my-app://soundcloud/callback.

From soundcloud docs

Comment: Yes that is true. I have used WebAuthenticationBroker and I have used CallbackUri but it is not redirecting me to the app after login.

Comment: I will setup and example to investigate that